# calling on the West take up a more active role -- is "take up" a subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctives

Example with [a context](http://foreignpolicy.com/2015/03/18/russian-duma-dissident-believes-west-must-save-ukraine-to-defeat-putin/):

> With the conflict in Ukraine showing little sign of coming to a peaceful resolution, Ponomarev now is calling on the West **take up** a more active role in reforming Ukraine’s political system and supporting its economy.

1. Is *take up* a subjunctive in this sentence?
2. Do you think it's possible to change the verb's mood to something more regular such as *to take up* (the infinitive form)? How do you think the meaning of the sentence would change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Take up* here is a mistake for ***to*** take up. A *mandative subjunctive* is a good guess, but the idiom *call on X* does not license that construction. It requires an infinitival complement:

> Ponomarev now is calling on the West **to take up** a more active role.